# Tiny MCE Editor removes non HTML part

Tags: tinymce

This problem is related to Tiny MCE Editor which is truncating my Non HTML part when I uncheck the option "Use raw HTML editor". Here are the steps:

1. Reach to the editor and paste my HTML (and Non HTML) content in the "Raw HTML" mode. This content is basically calling a Viddler Video and placing conditions for IE and non IE browsers like this : `<!--[if IE]>` and `<!--[if !IE]> <!-->`
2. Uncheck the option "Use raw HTML editor" and you see the video appears as it should in the "Preview" mode.
3. Now switch back to raw HTML option again by checking "Use raw HTML editor" and you would see that whatever HTML we had for non IE browsers that is which falls below `<!--[if !IE]> <!-->` gets truncated, I guess because Tiny editor does not recognize these `<!--[if IE]> and <!--[if !IE]> <!-->` and truncating whatever comes below this.

Here is my HTML code for your easy reference:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<object width="545" height="349" id="viddlerOuter-ba473db1" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
<param name="movie" value="//www.viddler.com/player/ba473db1/">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
<param name="allowNetworking" value="all">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<param name="flashVars" value="f=1&openURL=106922991&autoplay=f&loop=0&nologo=0&hd=0">
<object id="viddlerInner-ba473db1">
<video id="viddlerVideo-ba473db1" src="//www.viddler.com/file/ba473db1/html5mobile?openURL=106922991" type="video/mp4" width="545" height="307" poster="//www.viddler.com/thumbnail/ba473db1/" controls="controls" x-webkit-airplay="allow"></video>
</object>
</object>
<![endif]--> <!--[if !IE]> <!-->
<p>
<object id="viddlerOuter-ba473db1" width="545" height="349" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="//www.viddler.com/player/ba473db1/">
<param name="movie" value="//www.viddler.com/player/ba473db1/" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="flashVars" value="f=1&amp;openURL=106922991&amp;autoplay=f&amp;loop=0&amp;nologo=0&amp;hd=0" />
<object id="viddlerInner-ba473db1">
</object>
</object>
</p>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Workarounds that I have already tried are:
1. Verify_HTML : false
2. Cleanup : false

But no luck :(

Hope somebody able to help me out here.

Thanks in advance
Amit Arora

Comment: what versino of tinymce are you using? Cleanup parameter is deprecated and removed since 3.x

Comment: We are using tiny_mce_3_3_9_2. So what options I can try now ?

Comment: it is removed exactly since 3.4, so you still may use this setting (which should work) even though it is generally better to use a recent version of tinymce due to the development of new browser versions